# Run a loop while waiting for a user input

Tags: python, loops

I want to run a loop in my script while the user has not input anything. But when they have input something I want the loop to break.

The issue I am currently having is that when using the `input()` function, the script will stop and wait for an input, but I want to run another part of the script while waiting for the user input.

I have tried using `try:` with a `raw_input()`:

```
while True:
    try:
        print('SCAN BARCODE')
        userInput= raw_input()
        #doing something with input
    except:
        #run this while there is no input
```

With this, I find that whatever is in the `except:` will always run, but it will not run `try:` even when there is a user input. If I change `raw_input()` to `input()` the script just waits at `input()` and doesn't run anything in the `except:`.

How do I achieve what I am after?

Comment: Use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: what you need is a key event, check out [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)

Comment: This is precisely what you are looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71971926/18060246

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use python threads:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

thread_running = True


def my_forever_while():
    global thread_running

    start_time = time.time()

    # run this while there is no input
    while thread_running:
        time.sleep(0.1)

        if time.time() - start_time >= 5:
            start_time = time.time()
            print('Another 5 seconds has passed')


def take_input():
    user_input = input('Type user input: ')
    # doing something with the input
    print('The user input is: ', user_input)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target=my_forever_while)
    t2 = Thread(target=take_input)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t2.join()  # interpreter will wait until your process get completed or terminated
    thread_running = False
    print('The end')
```

In my example you have 2 threads, the first thread is up and executes code until you have some input from the user, thread 2 is waiting for some input from the user. After you got the user input thread 1 and 2 will stop.

Answer (score 1):

It simple bro u use flag boolean values

```
Flag = True
while Flag:
    try:
        Print('scan bar code')
        User_inp = input()
        if User_inp != '':
            Flag = False
    Except:
        Print('except part')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look for [select](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/select.html#select.select)

it allow you to check if a file descriptor is `ready` for read/write/expect operation